# Conditional plotting a geopackage

Tags: r, rgdal, geopackage

I have a geopackage for India taken from [GADM](https://gadm.org/). I can plot all the districts of India by using layer 1, all states using layer 3, and the whole country using layer 4. Here is the code:

```
> library(rgdal)
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 1.3-3, (SVN revision 759)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20
 Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/H.P/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/gdal
 GDAL binary built with GEOS: TRUE 
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016, [PJ_VERSION: 493]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/H.P/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/proj
 Linking to sp version: 1.3-1 
Warning message:
package ‘rgdal’ was built under R version 3.4.4 
> layers<-ogrListLayers("gdam36_IND.gpkg")
Error in ogrListLayers("gdam36_IND.gpkg") : Cannot open data source
> layers<-ogrListLayers("gadm36_IND.gpkg")
> x<-readOGR("gadm36_IND.gpkg",layers[3])
OGR data source with driver: GPKG 
Source: "C:\Users\H.P\Documents\gadm36_IND.gpkg", layer: "gadm36_IND_1"
with 36 features
It has 10 fields
> plot(x)
```

Which outputs :
[image]

I can get the summary of the variable `x` by:

```
> summary(x)
Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
Coordinates:
        min      max
x 68.186249 97.41516
y  6.754256 35.50133
Is projected: FALSE 
proj4string :
[+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0]
Data attributes:
 GID_0      NAME_0        GID_1                    NAME_1  
 IND:36   India:36   IND.1_1 : 1   Andaman and Nicobar: 1  
                     IND.10_1: 1   Andhra Pradesh     : 1  
                     IND.11_1: 1   Arunachal Pradesh  : 1  
                     IND.12_1: 1   Assam              : 1  
                     IND.13_1: 1   Bihar              : 1  
                     IND.14_1: 1   Chandigarh         : 1  
                     (Other) :30   (Other)            :30  
                                                                                                VARNAME_1 
 Ãles Laquedives|Laccadive|Minicoy and Amindivi Islands|Laccadives|Lackadiverna|Lakkadiven|Lakkadi  : 1  
 Agence de la FrontiÃ¨re du Nord-Est(French-obsolete)|North East Frontier Agency                     : 1  
 Andaman & Nicobar Islands|Andaman et Nicobar|Iihas de Andama e Nicobar|Inseln Andamanen und Nikobare: 1  
 Bangla|Bengala Occidentale|Bengala Ocidental|Bengale occidental                                     : 1  
 DAdra et Nagar Haveli|Dadra e Nagar Haveli                                                          : 1  
 (Other)                                                                                             : 9  
 NA's                                                                                                :22  
 NL_NAME_1            TYPE_1             ENGTYPE_1    CC_1        HASC_1  
 NA's:36   State         :28   State          :28   NA's:36   IN.AN  : 1  
           Union Territor: 8   Union Territory: 8             IN.AP  : 1  
                                                              IN.AR  : 1  
                                                              IN.AS  : 1  
                                                              IN.BR  : 1  
                                                              IN.CH  : 1  
                                                              (Other):30
```

Is there a way to plot only for a particular state? That is, for example, `x$NAME_1=="Chandigarh"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame as you would any other data frame:

```
plot(x[x$NAME_1=="Chandigarh",,drop=FALSE])
```

should do it.